# 111: Connection refused while connecting to upstream: supervisord Django channels Nginx

Tags: nginx, supervisord

I am a beginner on server side processes and the other questions that address this topic are running different stacks than I am so it's been quite hard to find useable answers.

It's very possible I am making a silly error with the IP addresses in the server block but again, as I am a beginner, it is not obvious.

I'm running a Django 2.1 application on Digital Ocean using `Nginx` and `supervisor`. My application uses `Django channels` which uses `daphne` hence I am using `supervisor` (`asgi` instead of `uwsgi`).

I've also registered with Let's Encrypt to get my SSL certificate.

Supervisor and Nginx are running and I see a

`502 Bad Gateway` when I type in my domain name.

The nginx log shows

```
2019/02/26 15:51:40 [error] 20187#20187: *8 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 86.xxx.xxx.14, server: myapp.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "www.myapp.com"
```

`sudo /usr/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`
 shows

```
2019-02-26 15:52:39,429 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2019-02-26 15:52:39,430 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/appname_asgi.conf" during parsing
2019-02-26 15:52:39,431 INFO Creating socket tcp://127.0.0.1:8000
2019-02-26 15:52:39,431 INFO Closing socket tcp://127.0.0.1:8000
Error: Another program is already listening on a port that one of our HTTP servers is configured to use.  Shut this program down first before starting supervisord.
```

Which obviously says another program is using `port 8000`.

However `sudo netstat -nlp | grep 8000` returns nothing.

## configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp:

```
upstream myapp {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}

server {
    server_name myapp.com www.myapp.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location /static/ {
        root /home/me/myapp/src/myapp;
    }

    location /media/  {
        root /home/me/myapp/src/myapp;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
        proxy_pass http://myapp;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}


server {
    if ($host = www.myapp.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = myapp.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.com www.myapp.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
```

## /etc/supervisor/conf.d/myapp_asgi.conf

```
[fcgi-program:asgi]
# TCP socket used by Nginx backend upstream
socket=tcp://127.0.0.1:8000

# Directory where your site's project files are located
directory=/home/me/myapp/src/myapp

# Each process needs to have a separate socket file, so we use process_num
# Make sure to update "mysite.asgi" to match your project name
command=daphne -u /home/me/daphne/run/daphne%(process_num)d.sock --f$

# Number of processes to startup, roughly the number of CPUs you have
numprocs=4

# Give each process a unique name so they can be told apart
process_name=asgi%(process_num)d

# Automatically start and recover processes
autostart=true
autorestart=true

# Choose where you want your log to go
stdout_logfile=/home/me/daphne/logs/asgi.log
redirect_stderr=true
```

## sudo netstat -peanut

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      112        2954261     11650/redis-server 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          3495386     19401/nginx -g daem
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          15750       1564/sshd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          3499269     19401/nginx -g daem
tcp        0    356 xxx.xx.xxx.76:22        xx.xx.xxx.14:52521     ESTABLISHED 0          3417368     13924/1         
tcp        0      0 xxx.xx.xxx.76:22        xx.xx.xxx.14:52528     ESTABLISHED 0          3418136     14131/2         
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      1000       2954691     11712/redis-server 
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          3495387     19401/nginx -g daem
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          15761       1564/sshd
```

I would appreciate if someone could look over this as, like I said, I'm sure the problem is obvious to someone with a higher skill level in this area.

Many thanks.

Comment: supervisord is failing to start daphne. It's not clear why that is. But you should be using systemd to start daphne anyway, not supervisord. See for instance [this tutorial](https://avilpage.com/2018/05/deploying-scaling-django-channels.html).

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your comment. I looked over that tutorial and it seems a bit over my head however I followed the `django_channels` docs which say "This example sets up a Django site on an Ubuntu server, using Nginx as the main webserver and supervisord to run and manage Daphne." https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying.html

Comment: They should give a better example then. They suggest using systemd, but they didn't give an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by changing to

```
command=/home/Env/myapp/bin/daphne -u /run/daphne/daphne%(process_num)d.sock --fd 0 --access-log - --proxy-headers mysite.asgi:application
```

so it was able to execute the `daphne` command